# No overload for '' matches delegate 'System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart'

Tags: c#, multithreading

If i have a method like this

```
  private void LoadModel(List<object> filenames)
{
}
```

and want to run this method in thread i make this

```
loadingThread = new ParameterizedThreadStart(LoadModel)
```

but give me error

how to solve this problem ?

```
No overload for 'LoadModel' matches delegate 'System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This delegate is defined as

```
public delegate void ParameterizedThreadStart(object obj)
```

You have to change your method declaration to match it:

```
private void LoadModel(object filenames)
```

and cast `filenames` to `List` in the method.

To create and start the thread use

```
Thread loadingThread = new Thread(LoadModel);
loadingThread.Start(filenames);
```

Instead of creating your own threads, consider using [Tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx) or [ThreadPool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 5):

Another way to solve your problem that allows your method to still have the type of the parameter that you want is to use a lambda expression like this:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() => LoadModel(list));
```

Where `list` is the parameter value that you want to pass.